# maxdatetime in odata URL

Tags: odata, odata4j

Hi have list of dates I need to get name where the maximum date is there.

In oData Service there is function `maxdatetime()`. I used like this

```
url/services/List?$format=json&$select=name&$filter=date+eq+maxdatetime()
```

But it is showing exception

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An unknown function with name 'maxdatetime' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."}}}
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function maxdatetime() should be implemented by service code. According to your exception, the service does not implement it. If you have right to change server side code, you can try to implement. Otherwise, Try:

```
RootUrl/List$filter=date eq 9999-12-31T11:59:59-00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Maya..How can i get maximum datetime using url from table?